# Programmatically Manipulating Printer Queues

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to develop a script that programmatically manipulates the printer queue of a particular device such that I can remove and append print jobs as needed according to certain conditions. Is there anyway that the printer queue can be programmatically accessed like this?

Comment: For what OS and what version of Python? There's [this](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32print.html) for Windows. I'm not sure if it's supported in Python3.

Comment: Python 2.7 is what I'm using, though I intend to port the script to have it work for all operating systems and printers.